# Keycloak Admin Api not getting right token

Tags: keycloak

Hi I wanna test out the Keycloak Admin API, but it doesn't seem to work.
I'm trying to call `http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/realms/master/users/count` on postman with GET.

For that I'm calling `http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token` with POST and `x-www-form-urlencoded` Body with this content:

```
username: admin
password: *
grant_type: password
client_id: admin-cli
```

That seems to work, as I'm getting an token back.
When only copying the `access_token` part into Authorization Bearer Token and calling the url from above, I always get back the response `401 Unauthorized`.

Surely I'm doing something wrong, might somebody help me out?

Comment: The default of the master token's `Access Token Lifespan` is 1 minute, if get it by Postman easy to pass one minute, and you needs to extend the Lifespan. In UI, in the master/Realm setting/Tokens tab, you can see that option.

Comment: I've increased the Lifespan to ten minutes, but still the same issue

Comment: Can you try my demo steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I demo to get master access token and get user count with it.

I am using [git bash](https://gitforwindows.org/) and [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/download/) for Windows.

#### #1 Launching Keycloak by Docker

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0.3 start-dev
```

The reason is the master access token's Lifespan is one minute as default.

It easily expires during you assign the Token environment variable and call to Keycloak API.

So you needs more time when you debugging or manual REST API calling by curl & Postman.

[image]

##### #2 Get Master Access Token and assign into MASTER_TOKEN variable.

```
MASTER_TOKEN=$(curl --silent --location --request POST "http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token" \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=admin-cli' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'username=admin' \
--data-urlencode 'password=admin' | jq -r '.access_token')
```

[image]

[image]

#### #3 Confirm it

```
echo $MASTER_TOKEN
```

[image]

#### #4 Add two users in `Master`

[image]

#### #5 Call User count API with token

Get user count API

```
http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/master/users/count
```

```
curl --silent --location --request GET "http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/master/users/count" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ""$MASTER_TOKEN"
```

#### Result

Got 3, it means two users count and admin.

[image]

[image]